# Adding new user in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I am using AWS RDS PostgreSQL and currently up and running. I would like to know how I can add a new user but only grant `SELECT` on an existing DB.

The way I connect to my RDS from my PC is by using a app called pgAdmin III (from Ubuntu).

I tried to create a group called `rds_guest`, assign a user (called `webkul`) and finally `GRANT` privileges (`INSERT`, `SELECT`, `UPDATE` etc) on the database I want for that particular group:

[image: pgAdmin III Admin Console]

When I try to login using that user and try perform actions on the desired database I get an error saying:

> Permission denied for relation xxx_yyy

Can anyone help me with this ? I am relatively new with Postgres.

Comment: Always show the **exact error message text**

Comment: @CraigRinger the error i get is "Permission denied for relation xxx_yyy

Answer (score 3):

You must grant a user:

- `CONNECT` on the database (if `public` doesn't have it by default)
- `USAGE` on any schemas like the `public` schema (again, if the `public` role doesn't have it by default)
- ... *and* the rights you want on a given table.

I suspect you (or RDS) have revoked `CONNECT` on the database and/or `USAGE` on the schema(s) you're using, so the role doesn't have the rights to get to the point where it can use the table privileges.

Comment: Should i do this via console or are any other means to do this ? i am getting "Permission denied for relation xxx_yyy" message.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html . You can probably use Pgadmin too.